# AuthenticationException error when I run nswag

Tags: .net, angular, aspnetboilerplate, nswag

My project is using Boilerplate(v.7) with dotnet core (.net6) with Angular(I upgraded to Angular14)
I compiled the backend and frontend with no error.
I run the backend and run refresh.bat ("..\node_modules.bin\nswag" run) on the frontend to generate services but I get the following error even though I created self sign certificate.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: did you find any solution to the above error ?